# Unable to use AdoJobStore in Quartz.NET

Tags: c#, scheduler, quartz.net

I'm trying to use AdoJobStore for scheduling Jobs using Quartz API.

This is the content of the Application Configuration File (present as part of Windows Service).

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="quartz"
             type="System.Configuration.NameValueSectionHandler" />
  </configSections>
  <quartz>
    <add key="quartz.scheduler.instanceName" value="ServerScheduler" />
    <add key="quartz.threadPool.type" value="Quartz.Simpl.SimpleThreadPool, Quartz" />
    <add key="quartz.threadPool.threadCount" value="10" />
    <add key="quartz.threadPool.threadPriority" value="2" />
    <add key="quartz.jobStore.misfireThreshold" value="60000" />
    <add key="quartz.jobStore.useProperties" value="true" />
    <add key="quartz.jobStore.clustered" value="true" />
    <add key="quartz.jobStore.lockHandler.type" value="Quartz.Impl.AdoJobStore.UpdateLockRowSemaphore, Quartz" />
    <add key="quartz.jobStore.type" value="Quartz.Impl.AdoJobStore.JobStoreTX, Quartz" />
    <add key="quartz.jobStore.driverDelegateType" value="Quartz.Impl.AdoJobStore.StdAdoDelegate, Quartz" />
    <add key="quartz.jobStore.dataSource" value="quartzDS" />
    <add key="quartz.dataSource.quartzDS.connectionString" value="Data Source=LocalDB;User ID=wesly;Password=XXXXX" />
    <add key="quartz.dataSource.quartzDS.provider" value="OracleClient-20 " />
   </quartz>
</configuration>
```

When I Start my Windows Service I m getting the following error formatted and written to logs:

> Exception Source: Quartz Exception Method:Quartz.IScheduler
>   Instantiate() Exception StackTrace:    at
>   Quartz.Impl.StdSchedulerFactory.Instantiate() in
>   c:\Work\OpenSource\Quartz.NET\quartznet\src\Quartz\Impl\StdSchedulerFactory.cs:line
>   1044    at Quartz.Impl.StdSchedulerFactory.GetScheduler() in
>   c:\Work\OpenSource\Quartz.NET\quartznet\src\Quartz\Impl\StdSchedulerFactory.cs:line
>   1118    at SampleJobScheduling.ScheduleJob.Run() in
>   C:\Users\jwesly\documents\visual studio
>   2010\Projects\SampleJobScheduling\SampleJobScheduling\ScheduleJob.cs:line
>   25 Exception Message: Could not Initialize DataSource: quartzDS

I'm using Oracle 11g Express Edition. Schema is WESLY

Please help !!!

Comment: You should examine the stack trace. It should contain a more specific error. Also if using Oracle you should use OracleDelegate instead of StdAdoDelegate.

Comment: Hi Marko.. Thanks a lot!!! the above issue was due to unavailability of data provider for oracle in my system. I downloaded provider from oracle website and issue resolved.

Comment: Actually the solution you have proposed solved one of my biggest issue which I've posted as another question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20298946/facing-issues-storing-job-through-adojobstore

Comment: I find this Quartz scheduler indeed interesting and I've spent for the past 3 days in exploring the features. I've couple of questions though for which I couldnt get any answer. I would like to ask those questions to you. Please let me know the means to communicate with you to get those clarifications.

Comment: I've posted one of my question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20321142/scheduling-jobs-using-quartz-need-opinion

Answer (score 3):

I was faced this exception after using version 3 of quartz.net.
According to [BREAKING CHANGES](https://www.quartz-scheduler.net/2017/12/30/quartznet-3.0-released.html) of Version 3; provider type was simplified.
It can't read old provider type then data source is failing to initialize.
you should change:

```
<add key="quartz.dataSource.quartzDS.provider" value="OracleClient-20 "/>
```

to:

```
<add key="quartz.dataSource.quartzDS.provider" value="OracleODP" />
```

and you should add serializer type property like:

```
<add key="quartz.serializer.type" value="binary" />
```

Because you aren't using **RamJobStore**.
read about it here: [Version Migration Guide](https://www.quartz-scheduler.net/documentation/quartz-3.x/migration-guide.html)

Answer (score 3):

I was faced the same problem with mssql configuration.
The old settings was the following:

```
["quartz.dataSource.default.provider"] = "SqlServer-20"
```

I have to change to:

```
["quartz.dataSource.default.provider"] = "SqlServer",
["quartz.serializer.type"] = "binary"
```

Thanks nimeresam