# Facing Issues Storing Job through AdoJobStore

Tags: c#, triggers, quartz-scheduler, ado, odp.net

I've successfully connected to Oracle DB from AdoJobStore. But when I try to add a job I m getting the following exception.

> Exception Source: Quartz Exception Method: Void
>   StoreJob(Quartz.Impl.AdoJobStore.ConnectionAndTransactionHolder,
>   Quartz.IJobDetail, Boolean) Exception StackTrace:    at
>   Quartz.Impl.AdoJobStore.JobStoreSupport.StoreJob(ConnectionAndTransactionHolder
>   conn, IJobDetail newJob, Boolean replaceExisting) in
>   c:\Work\OpenSource\Quartz.NET\quartznet\src\Quartz\Impl\AdoJobStore\JobStoreSupport.cs:line
>   922    at
>   Quartz.Impl.AdoJobStore.JobStoreSupport.<>c_*DisplayClass4.b*_3(ConnectionAndTransactionHolder conn) in
>   c:\Work\OpenSource\Quartz.NET\quartznet\src\Quartz\Impl\AdoJobStore\JobStoreSupport.cs:line
>   848    at
>   Quartz.Impl.AdoJobStore.JobStoreSupport.ExecuteInNonManagedTXLock[T](String
>   lockName, Func`2 txCallback, Func`3 txValidator) in
>   c:\Work\OpenSource\Quartz.NET\quartznet\src\Quartz\Impl\AdoJobStore\JobStoreSupport.cs:line
>   3514    at
>   Quartz.Impl.AdoJobStore.JobStoreSupport.ExecuteInNonManagedTXLock[T](String
>   lockName, Func`2 txCallback) in
>   c:\Work\OpenSource\Quartz.NET\quartznet\src\Quartz\Impl\AdoJobStore\JobStoreSupport.cs:line
>   3432    at Quartz.Impl.AdoJobStore.JobStoreTX.ExecuteInLock[T](String
>   lockName, Func`2 txCallback) in
>   c:\Work\OpenSource\Quartz.NET\quartznet\src\Quartz\Impl\AdoJobStore\JobStoreTX.cs:line
>   76    at
>   Quartz.Impl.AdoJobStore.JobStoreSupport.StoreJobAndTrigger(IJobDetail
>   newJob, IOperableTrigger newTrigger) in
>   c:\Work\OpenSource\Quartz.NET\quartznet\src\Quartz\Impl\AdoJobStore\JobStoreSupport.cs:line
>   845    at Quartz.Core.QuartzScheduler.ScheduleJob(IJobDetail
>   jobDetail, ITrigger trigger) in
>   c:\Work\OpenSource\Quartz.NET\quartznet\src\Quartz\Core\QuartzScheduler.cs:line
>   718    at Quartz.Impl.StdScheduler.ScheduleJob(IJobDetail jobDetail,
>   ITrigger trigger) in
>   c:\Work\OpenSource\Quartz.NET\quartznet\src\Quartz\Impl\StdScheduler.cs:line
>   262    at TestScheduling.TestScheduleJob.Run() in
>   C:\Users\jwesly\documents\visual studio
>   2010\Projects\TestScheduling\TestScheduling\TestScheduleJob.cs:line 25
>   **> Exception Message: Couldn't store job: Value does not fall within the
>   expected range.**

Here is the code where I've scheduled a Job.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using Quartz;
using Quartz.Impl;
using System.IO;

namespace TestScheduling
{
    class TestScheduleJob : ITaskScheduler
    {
        IScheduler sched;
        public void Run()
        {
            try
            {
                JobDataMap jobdata = new JobDataMap();
                jobdata.Add("mtid", "value");
                IJobDetail job = JobBuilder.Create<TestJob>().WithIdentity("job1", "group1").UsingJobData(jobdata).RequestRecovery(true).Build();
                DateTimeOffset dt = new DateTimeOffset(DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(10));
                ISimpleTrigger trig = (ISimpleTrigger)TriggerBuilder.Create().StartAt(dt).WithSimpleSchedule(x => x.WithIntervalInSeconds(10).WithRepeatCount(5)).Build();
                ISchedulerFactory sf = new StdSchedulerFactory();
                sched = sf.GetScheduler();
                sched.ScheduleJob(job, trig);
                sched.Start();
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                StreamWriter streamWriter = new StreamWriter(new FileStream("C:\\test_schedule_job_error.txt", FileMode.Append));
                String exceptionEntry = "Exception Source:\n" + e.Source + "\n" + "Exception Method:\n" + e.TargetSite + "\n" + "Exception StackTrace:\n" + e.StackTrace + "\n" + "Exception Message:\n" + e.Message;
                streamWriter.WriteLine(exceptionEntry);
                streamWriter.Close();
                throw e;
            }
            finally
            {
            }
        }
        public void Stop()
        {
            if (sched != null)
            {
                sched.Shutdown();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Please help !!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be using OracleDelegate instead of StdAdoDelegate. Define in configuration using

```
properties["quartz.jobStore.driverDelegateType"] = "Quartz.Impl.AdoJobStore.OracleDelegate, Quartz";
```